# Creating my own version of the access() function

Tags: c, linux

The context here is this is an university exercise.
We're using C on a Linux Machine.

Using (I assume) `stat()`, I need to make a function that works like `access()`, by which I mean by sending a path and an octal number, it will check if the permission associated with said octal number are true for the real user or not.

```
int my_acess (const char *path, int mode)
```

I know that `st_mode` contains the file mode, I just don't know how to actually use it. I'm assuming the last 3 digits I see are the ones referring to the mode so far, I got this done.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
 
int my_acess (const char *path, int mode){
    struct stat buf;
    int check;
    int f, f2;
    int pmode;

    check=stat(path, &buf);
    if (check==-1) return -1;
    //printf("%o\n",buf.st_mode%512); used this to examine how st_mode worked
    pmode=buf.st_mode%512;
    f=getuid();
    f2=getgid();
    if (f==buf.st_uid)
        printf("you're the owner\n");
    else if (f2==buf.st_gid)
        printf("you're part of the group\n");
    else
        printf("you're other\n");
 
    return -1;
}
```

Now that this part of the program is done... I just need to select the right octal number digit, which I'm not really sure how to do besides maybe dividing the octal number by 8 or 64?... convert both the octal numbers (pmode and mode) into binary (which I'm not sure if there's a "fast way" to do it besides just dividing by 2) and do an AND between each other and see if the resulting binary number is the same as the one in the variable mode (I don't even know if I need a special library for this).

This is how I think you're suppose to to implement this function, but maybe I'm overthinking it. Is there something I'm overlooking? A function or maybe a boolean macro that I forgot?

Comment: Do you mean [access()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/access.html) function?

Comment: `buf.st_mode%512` is a very odd way to masking bits. More common would be e.g. `buf.st_mode & 0777` or `buf.st_mode & 0x1ff`.

Comment: [one example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-base-decimal-vice-versa/) of how to convert between radix in C

Comment: I wasn't aware there was an & operator for C, this actually solves most of my problems; Mainly i don't have to convert from oct to binary to oct again, I can just theoretically do the & between both oct numbers. Still, I need to select which of the 3 digits of mode I need. Is there a less awkward way to do this outside of dividing by 8?

Comment: @Maridiama. Numbers are numbers. It doesn't matter if you write `0777`, `511` or `1FF`: it's the same integer either way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's not that I'm dividing by 8 to convert a number, I'm doing so that I can get a certain digit. if I have 724 (oct) and I want to get the '2' I need to divide by 8 and mask the 7 with &07.

Comment: @Maridiama. Internally, the number is stored in binary. Divisibility properties do not change based on how you represent a number. If you want the n-th bit, the most idiomatic approach is to do something like `(number >> n) & 1`. If you want three bits starting with the 4th, you can do `(number >> 3) & 7`. Welcome to the world of bit twiddling. Also, `07`, `7` and `0x7` are the same thing. C doesn't care how *you* perfer to look at it. It's the same number either way.

Comment: "I have 724 (oct)" It is not oct. It is decimal. Octal numbers are spelled with a leading 0: 0724. You don't need to convert 0724 to anything, it already has the value you need. Converting decimal 724 to octal 0724 is probably not what they want you to do.

Comment: To get 2 out of 0724, you can do the division-and-remainder thing `((0724 / 8) % 8)` or the bit-shift-and-mask thing `((0724 >> 3) & 7)`. It's the same thing and even produces identical machine code on many compilers. You can write a couple of functions or macros to make it less awkward.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), *st_mode* field contains two information:

- The file type that you can check with the following macros: **S_ISREG**(buf.st_mode)
  (regular file?), **S_ISDIR**(buf.st_mode) (directory?), **S_ISCHR**(buf.st_mode) (character device?), **S_ISBLK**(buf.st_mode) (block device?), **S_ISFIFO**(buf.st_mode) (named pipe?), **S_ISLNK**(buf.st_mode) (symbolic link?), **S_ISSOCK**(buf.st_mode) (socket?)
- The access rights that you can check with a binary & operation with the following macros defined in *<sys/stat.h>*

```c
#define S_IRUSR __S_IREAD   /* Read by owner.  */
#define S_IWUSR __S_IWRITE  /* Write by owner.  */
#define S_IXUSR __S_IEXEC   /* Execute by owner.  */
/* Read, write, and execute by owner.  */
#define S_IRWXU (__S_IREAD|__S_IWRITE|__S_IEXEC)

#define S_IRGRP (S_IRUSR >> 3)  /* Read by group.  */
#define S_IWGRP (S_IWUSR >> 3)  /* Write by group.  */
#define S_IXGRP (S_IXUSR >> 3)  /* Execute by group.  */
/* Read, write, and execute by group.  */
#define S_IRWXG (S_IRWXU >> 3)

#define S_IROTH (S_IRGRP >> 3)  /* Read by others.  */
#define S_IWOTH (S_IWGRP >> 3)  /* Write by others.  */
#define S_IXOTH (S_IXGRP >> 3)  /* Execute by others.  */
/* Read, write, and execute by others.  */
#define S_IRWXO (S_IRWXG >> 3)
```

So, if you need to check the type, you can write something like:

```c
if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
  // It is a directory
}
```

If you need to check the access bits:

```c
if (buf.st_mode & S_IRUSR) {
  // File readable by user
}
```